# jsonrpc-lean VS. cURL?

Tags: json-rpc

I wanna try and develop a small miner where anyone could see the backbone of it, so that everyone would know how everything works. Now I wanna ask whether what to use should I use for communicating with the pool, [jsonrpc-lean](https://github.com/uskr/jsonrpc-lean) or libcurl, I am not only trying to build just for bitcoin maybe some other altcoin like monero too.

but One big question. Is mining in bitcoin and monero the same? except for the fact that of course you should claculate (decrypt) them differently, what I mean was the way they work with the pool. (request infos from the pool, calculate it and submit it)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the mining pool and the software they are using. There is no one specific way for mining pools for a specific coins to relay information to their miners. For Bitcoin, most use stratum or getblocktemplate. For stratum, I don't think either of the libraries will work as stratum is not served over HTTP.